# Launching my own app only as the default app for android

Tags: android-3.0-honeycomb, android

I have to build an app for android 3.0 tab in which I have to launch my own app as the only deafult app for android and also the user can use the device through that app only and have limited access(can use limited app).The Home button also get disabled.

The main screen of the app will be a login screen using which user will login by some specific username and password and also he will give the time period   for which he want to access the device and he has to pay some money through paypal. Once the time period finishes the app automatically get closed and launches again.

Actually, we want to use the tablet for commercial purpose and want to build an app through which user can use the tablet for some specific time period by paying some money.

Please give me some idea  on the app(whether its feasible or not).
Also provide me few links which can help me to build the project.

Very urgent.Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should make your app a launcher with the following intent filter :
`<intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>

</intent-filter>`

This will not deactivate your home button but will launch, or at least ask the user to launch your app on press.

If you have full hand on the tablet itself, remove the launcher2.apk and let only your launcher, this will do the trick, no other launcher will be launchable.

Since your are the launcher you can decide where the user can go from here you have control of any user the action can do.

Comment: how can I remove launcher2.apk as I want my app as the only launcher.

Comment: this is possible only if your have full hand on the device, an app can't do such thing. The launcher is in /data/app/launcher2.apk (might require root) maybe you can simply uninstall it from parameters/app.

Comment: What is the this **android.intent.category.MONKEY** and what is its use. Can you explain the above comment. I could not get you. Can we change the default functionality of android prgramatically ..?   Uninstalling /data/app/launcher2.apk  may harm my device in any way..?

Comment: this is the intent filter of the default launcher app, the monkey is not required,`This activity may be exercised by the monkey or other automated test tools.`if your are not root, uninstalling launcher might get you in trouble. Backup your launcher using adb pull, make sure your are root, uninstall launcher2.apk (if possible, or simply delete the apk), put your apk, reboot, if you are in any trouble, put back the launcher2.apk in the correct place(in any case you might want to read some info at: http://forum.xda-developers.com/)

Comment: I could not take the backup of launcher.apk(found in system/app folder). how can I and also how can I replace this one with my own app. Please help.

Comment: you should be able to run adb -d pull /system/app/launcher.apk ./ or (launcher2.apk)